# Change BODY background color when hovering over a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I'm playing around with an idea I have. What I want to accomplish is to have a 6x6 table, and as you hover over a cell, it will change the **BODY** background color. I plan on only applying this to select cells in this table.

As of right now, I have it working with a single div. After a lot of googling and searching on StackOverflow, I can't for the life of me get it working with a table.

**CSS:**

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}

#bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    widht: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #EEE;
}

#cell {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 136px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -68px 0 0 -100px;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 2;
}

#cell:hover ~ #bg {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="cell"></div>
<div id="bg"></div>
```

**JSFiddle (ADDED TO SHOW THE BEHAVIOR I AM TRYING TO PRODUCE):** http://jsfiddle.net/yrKRX/169/

I'm open to jQuery, javascript, or pure CSS solutions, whatever would work the easiest.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What do you mean by select cells?

Comment: Couldn't you provide then a relevant jsFiddle regarding your issue?

Comment: @A.Wolff I did include a JSFiddle.

Comment: @RahilWazir I'm only going to be applying this to about half of the cells.

Comment: @MathewMacLean but this jsFiddle doesn't include any TABLE and anyway, works as expected. Do i misunderstand your question?!

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, my question states that I have it working with a div. I cannot, in anyway, shape, or form, replicate the same behavior with a table cell.

Comment: @MathewMacLean So then, couldn't you post a jsFiddle relative to your issue???! What don't you understand in previous comment?

Comment: @A.Wolff That would be me just adding an empty table. What I am asking is how I can replicate this behavior on a table cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to change dynamically use jQuery and listen to mouseenter and mouseleave events:

```
$('#myTable tr td.someClass').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $('body').css( "background-color", "yellow");
})
$('#myTable tr td.someClass').on('mouseleave',function(){
   $('body').css( "background-color", "white");
});
```

Here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/yrKRX/172/

Comment: This works, but it applies it to all cells in a table. I'm looking to only have it apply to a select few.

Comment: @MathewMacLean which ones? Don't you think you are missing important part in your question?!

Comment: It doesn't matter which ones. Even if the tables are selected at random. As long as I have the ability to apply the solution to whichever cell I choose.

Comment: So change the selector: add class to ones that you need and that's itI've updated fiddle and answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using CSS classes would be more flexible. Also JS can be shorter:

```
$('table').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.hover', function(e) {
    $('body').toggleClass('active', e.type == 'mouseenter');
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e57gF/

Answer (score 2):

A solution using jQuery:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="foo">Foo</td>
            <td id="bar">Bar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="baz">Baz</td>
            <td id="tux">Tux</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

and

```
// Background change on td hover
$('#foo').hover(function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', '#FF0000');
},function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', '');
});

$('#bar').hover(function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', '#00FF00');
},function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', '');
});

$('#baz').hover(function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', '#0000FF');
},function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', '');
});

$('#tux').hover(function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', '#000000');
},function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', '');
});
```

Not exactly elegant, but it gets the job done.

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yrKRX/171/)

Comment: This works quite well, and would be perfect for anyone looking to use multiple colors! Thank you for your answer. I have already accepted Good.luck's answer but will definitely vote yours up.

Comment: A little advice: use ids like 'id1','id2' and so on, and then just make the selector like 'td[id^=id]', it will make your code much shorter

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to hardcode your `background-color` values, then provide the color in your id attribute. Something like this: [**Check The Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yrKRX/174/)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td id="red">one</td>
    <td id="blue">two</td>
    <td id="green">three</td>
</tr>
</table>

var $body = $('body');
$('td').mouseover(function(){
    var bgColor = $(this).attr("id");
    $body.css('backgroundColor', bgColor);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $body.css('backgroundColor', 'white');
});
```

A Tip: When you see that you are calling the same thing again and again, better store it in a variable like I did it for the `body` tag.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the "Body" part!